# How to use custom Links to display specific page with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Ok So Im Finally putting the finishing touches on my website and I noticed that It will be hard for me to promote certain sections of the website considering that the address in the browser never changes. If you visit my page I have several links that open up in a div with ajax coding. Now Lets Say I wanted to promote a link to a specific place or page on my website I wont be able to becuase the link will only point back to the main page. How Do I Get the website to load specifically to the page links when clicked. Meaning How do I promote certain page or section on my website with a seperate link versus having to send the user to one link and they have to search for the content or what ever they are looking for.

DEMO: http://trillumonopoly.com/index2.html

Heres My CODING:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<title>iLLumonopoly Global ::The Next Level::</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="language" content="English"> 
<meta name="description" content="Illumonopoly Global is the best and the first I.M.M.P (International Mass Media Production) of its generation. We Provide many services with Quality products and reasonable rates with the fastest turn around times Online. We house Several Business In many different markets. We Focus on Helping you to develop your Brand and elevating your business to the next level. A List Service, A List Staff, for our A List Clients. Let Us Help You Elevate your brand to The Next Level. Illumonopoly Global">
<meta name="keywords" content="Rap, hip hop, hip-hop, blog, Musical instruments, beat machine, maschine, pro tools, mixer, microphone, distribution, music distribution, video distribution, radio promotions, radio, mixtape, T. Cartel, T. Cvrt3l, Todd Gotti, T. Gotti, Bricksquad, Zareyah, Zareyah evolved, beats, trap music, Vevo, MTV,Spotify, 2 Chainz, Def Jam, Universal Music Group, FDE, Printing, Audio, Video, Production, Audio Production, Beats, Video Production, Email Blast, Promotion, Product, Services, Printing Services, Cheap Printing Services, Cheap Beats, Graphic Design, Logo Design, Flyer Design, Poster Design, Blue Lines and Big Faces, Facebook marketing, Twitter marketing, Youtube views, Datpiff marketing,  ">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="KpWnMe8Ghac9bdfocoBvVgALEGCe1zHqTFO2ZTHjaXo" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.fullwidthAudioPlayer.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fjalla+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allura&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/set1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="content/global.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.snipcart.com/scripts/snipcart.js" id="snipcart"
  data-api-key="ZDZiMGY0NjEtODk2NC00NDM3LWIyNjctZTE5M2I4NzFiMjRmNjM1ODkzMTg4NzE1MjMzMDIw"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="https://cdn.snipcart.com/themes/base/snipcart.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="java/FWDMSP.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo-4.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    FWDMSPUtils.onReady(function(){
        new FWDMSP({
            //main settings
            instanceName:"player1",
            playlistsId:"playlists",
            mainFolderPath:"content",
            skinPath:"minimal_skin_white",
            facebookAppId:"213684265480896",//required only if the facebook share button is used
            showSoundCloudUserNameInTitle:"yes",
            position:"bottom",
            useDeepLinking:"no",
            rightClickContextMenu:"disabled",
            showButtonsToolTips:"yes",
            animate:"yes",
            autoPlay:"yes",
            loop:"no",
            shuffle:"no",
            maxWidth:1030,
            volume:.8,
            toolTipsButtonsHideDelay:1.5,
            toolTipsButtonFontColor:"#888888",
            //controller settings
            showControllerByDefault:"yes",
            showThumbnail:"yes",
            showSoundAnimation:"yes",
            showLoopButton:"yes",
            showShuffleButton:"no",
            showDownloadMp3Button:"yes",
            showBuyButton:"yes ",
            showFacebookButton:"no",
            expandBackground:"no",
            titleColor:"#000000",
            timeColor:"#000000",
            //controller align and size settings (described in detail in the documentation!)
            controllerHeight:76,
            startSpaceBetweenButtons:9,
            spaceBetweenButtons:8,
            separatorOffsetOutSpace:5,
            separatorOffsetInSpace:9,
            lastButtonsOffsetTop:14,
            allButtonsOffsetTopAndBottom:14,
            titleBarOffsetTop:13,
            mainScrubberOffsetTop:47,
            spaceBetweenMainScrubberAndTime:10,
            startTimeSpace:10,
            scrubbersOffsetWidth:2,
            scrubbersOffestTotalWidth:0,
            volumeButtonAndScrubberOffsetTop:47,
            spaceBetweenVolumeButtonAndScrubber:6,
            volumeScrubberOffestWidth:4,
            scrubberOffsetBottom:10,
            equlizerOffsetLeft:1,
            //playlists window settings
            showPlaylistsButtonAndPlaylists:"no",
            showPlaylistsByDefault:"no",
            thumbnailSelectedType:"opacity",
            startAtPlaylist:20,
            startAtTrack:0,
            buttonsMargins:0,
            thumbnailMaxWidth:330, 
            thumbnailMaxHeight:330,
            horizontalSpaceBetweenThumbnails:40,
            verticalSpaceBetweenThumbnails:40,
            //playlist settings
            showPlayListButtonAndPlaylist:"no",
            showPlayListOnAndroid:"no",
            showPlayListByDefault:"no",
            showPlaylistItemPlayButton:"yes",
            showPlaylistItemDownloadButton:"yes",
            showPlaylistItemBuyButton:"yes",
            forceDisableDownloadButtonForPodcast:"yes",
            forceDisableDownloadButtonForOfficialFM:"yes",
            forceDisableDownloadButtonForFolder:"yes",
            addScrollBarMouseWheelSupport:"yes",
            showTracksNumbers:"yes",
            playlistBackgroundColor:"#ffa500",
            trackTitleNormalColor:"#888888",
            trackTitleSelectedColor:"#FFFFFF",
            trackDurationColor:"#666666",
            maxPlaylistItems:100,
            nrOfVisiblePlaylistItems:12,
            trackTitleOffsetLeft:0,
            playPauseButtonOffsetLeftAndRight:11,
            durationOffsetRight:9,
            downloadButtonOffsetRight:11,
            scrollbarOffestWidth:7,
            //search bar settings
            showSearchBar:"no",
            showSortButtons:"yes",
            searchInputColor:"#999999",
            searchBarHeight:38,
            //opener settings
            openerAlignment:"right",
            showOpener:"yes",
            showOpenerPlayPauseButton:"yes",
            openerEqulizerOffsetLeft:3,
            openerEqulizerOffsetTop:-1,
            //popup settings
            showPopupButton:"no",
            popupWindowBackgroundColor:"#878787",
            popupWindowWidth:850,
            popupWindowHeight:354
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>




<style>


body {
       font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif !important;
}

/* Let's get this party started */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); 
}       
</style>
<style>
.navbar-fixed-top{bottom:0;margin-bottom:0px;border-width:0px 0 0; height:40px !important; border-top-color:Orange  !important; z-index:999; background-color: white !important;};
</style>

<style> body { 
  background: url(../images/background.jpg) fixed; 
  background-color: white !important;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top:70px;
  margin-bottom:45px;
  color: black !important;
}
input, select, textarea {
color: Black;
}

.navbar-default{
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 0px #666;    
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: #AAA;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 0px #000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: white;
    background-color: silver;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 0px #ffffff;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>
<ul id="playlists" style="display:none;">
<li data-source="folder:music/011BlueLines" data-thumbnail-path="https://trillumonopoly.com/content/thumbnails/BLuelinesAndBigFaces.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Blue Lines & Big Faces</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">GENERATE FROM FOLDER</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created from a folder of mp3 files.</p>
    </li>  


   <li data-source="playlist1" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>BLUE LINES AND BIG FACES</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">HTML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using html elements.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/flipdatent-ceo-t-cartel/t-cartel-panties-drop-radio" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large2.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>PANTIES DROP</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">Soundcloud</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>New Single</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/flipdatent-ceo-t-cartel/sidebishradio" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large2.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>SIDE CHICK</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">SoundCloud</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>New Single</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/001DoinNumbers" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Doin Numbers</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>   

    <li data-source="folder:music/0022PotentAlbum" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>2 Potent Album</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/003PotentAlbum" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Tha Potent Album</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>


<li data-source="folder:music/004DGvol1" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Divine Grind Vol.1</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/006KeepItG" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Keep It G</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/007IAmAG" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>I Am A G</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/008GodsHand" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>GodsHand</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>

     <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/ruger_gotti/kilt-dat-at-outta-sight-outta" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large3.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Kilt Dat</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">SOUNDCLOUD</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a SoundCloud playlist URL.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/009RNL" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>RNL</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/flipdatent-ceo-t-cartel/dope-boi-ft-zae-the-godd" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large3.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Dope Boi</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">SOUNDCLOUD</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a SoundCloud playlist URL.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/flipdatent-ceo-t-cartel/t-cartel-millions" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large3.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Millions</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">SOUNDCLOUD</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a SoundCloud playlist URL.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/010YungNGettinIt" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large1.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Yung N Gettin It</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">XML</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a XML file.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/todd-gotti-594618109/oya" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large3.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>OYA</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">SOUNDCLOUD</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a SoundCloud playlist URL.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/todd-gotti-594618109/paparazzi-w-nard-bruno-satelite" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large3.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Paparazzi</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">SOUNDCLOUD</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a SoundCloud playlist URL.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="folder:music/005GunsmokeNResin" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large3.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Gunsmoke & Resin</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">FOLDER</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a SoundCloud playlist URL.</p>
    </li>

    <li data-source="https://soundcloud.com/todd-gotti-594618109/beat-it-down-feat-eskimo-eazy" data-thumbnail-path="content/thumbnails/large3.jpg">
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesTitle"><span class="bold">Title: </span>Beat It Down</p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesType"><span class="bold">Type: </span><span class="minimalDarkCategoriesTypeIn">SOUNDCLOUD</span></p>
        <p class="minimalDarkCategoriesDescription"><span class="bold">Description: </span>This playlist is created using a SoundCloud playlist URL.</p>
    </li>

</ul>


      <!--Navigation-->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
               <div class="container-fluid">

                        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"><a href="http://www.trillumonopoly.com/index2.html"><img src="../images/iLLLogo.png"  class="img-responsive hidden-xs hidden-sm "></a></div>

                            <div class="col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                      <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#homenav">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button> 


      </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="homenav">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
    <li><a href="pages/main.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Home</span>
        <span>-Home-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a></li>

          <li> <a href="pages/artist.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Roster</span>
        <span>-Roster-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a></li>
<li>
 <a href="pages/order.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Beats</span>
        <span>-Beats-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a>    
           </li> <li>
          <a href="pages/music.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Music</span>
        <span>-Music-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a>    
           </li>     
            <li>
          <a href="pages/videos.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Videos</span>
        <span>-Videos-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a> </li>
<li>
<a href="pages/videos.php" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Store</span>
        <span>-Store-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a>    
    </li>
    <li>          
               <a href="pages/services.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Services</span>
        <span>-Services-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a> 
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu_nav demo-4">
      <span>
        <span>Resources</span>
        <span>-Resources-</span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a>       </li>

    <li>
            <a href="#" class="demo-4 snipcart-checkout">
      <span>
        <span>YOUR CART: </span>
        <span><div class="snipcart-summary"><span class="snipcart-total-price"></span></div></span>
        <span></span>
      </span>
    </a>       </li>


    </ul>

            </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1"><div class="navbar-right">
                <a href="#" class=""><font color="black" ></span></font></a></span>
            </div></div>




               </div>     
      </nav>
      <!--End Of Navigation-->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: rgba (0,0,0, 0.7)">
                                <center><div class="row" id="contentarea"></div></center>

                                <br>
                                <div class="container" id="footer" style="border-radius:5px; border-color:black; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8)">
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><h2><font color="Gray">Twitter</font></h2><BR>
                                    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Illumonopoly101" data-widget-id="691098558792142849">Tweets by @Illumonopoly101</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
<br>
                                    <BR></div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><h2><font color="Gray">Facebook</font></h2><BR>
                                        <div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/foreverdigiempire" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/foreverdigiempire"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/foreverdigiempire">Forever Digi Empi</a></blockquote></div></div><br>
                                    <BR> </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4"><h2><font color="Gray">ACCOUNT</font></h2><BR><BR> </div>
                                </div><br><br><br><br>
            </div>




            </div>
        </div>        



<script src="js/nav.js"></script>

<script language=JavaScript>
<!--


var message="Thats Property iLLumonopoly Global Publishing. Unauthorized Duplication is prohibited";
///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}}
function clickNS(e) {if 
(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) {
if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}}
if (document.layers) 
{document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);document.onmousedown=clickNS;}
else{document.onmouseup=clickNS;document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
// --> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher: "f497004f-2790-48d8-888b-6fec35fdf757", doNotHash: false, doNotCopy: false, hashAddressBar: false});</script>
<script>
var options={ "publisher": "f497004f-2790-48d8-888b-6fec35fdf757", "position": "left", "ad": { "visible": false, "openDelay": 5, "closeDelay": 0}, "chicklets": { "items": ["facebook", "twitter", "googleplus", "myspace", "pinterest", "blogger", "email", "sharethis"]}};
var st_hover_widget = new sharethis.widgets.hoverbuttons(options);
</script> 
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-72805834-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Heres My Ajax Code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: "pages/main.html",
    success: function(content)
    {
        $('#contentarea').html (content);
    }
});
    });



$('.menu_nav') .click (function () {
var href = $(this) .attr('href');
$('#contentarea').hide() .load(href).slideDown( 'very slow' )

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
(function() {
    $('.menu_nav').on('click',function () {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href = href.slice(0, -5); // remove .html so URL is not that ugly
        window.location.hash = href;
        $('#contentarea').hide().load('pages/'+href+'.html').slideDown('very slow');
        return false;
    });

    function hash(){
        var href = window.location.hash.substr(1); // get hash from URL
        if(href){
            $('#contentarea').hide().load('pages/'+href+'.html').slideDown('very slow');
        }else{
            $('#contentarea').hide().load('pages/main.html').slideDown('very slow');
        }
    }

    $(window).bind('hashchange', hash);
    $(document).on('ready', hash);
})();
```

With this hash is set in URL and loads that page on click.
Also, on hash change and on page load it checks if there is hash in URL. If yes it loads corresponding page and if not it loads `main.html`.
So you can link to desired page/hash like this for example `yourdomain.com/index2.html#somepage`

Comment: where do I put the hash? on the Page? or in the Code? Not fully understanding this.... but It looks right

Comment: you are just putting it in URL/link that you want to share/promote.. like this `yourdomain.com/index2.html#somepage`... You don't have to put it in code. It is generated from your href links

Comment: This isnt working for me...... Ive tried to put the hash in the link but its not working. am I suppose to name the links or something.... like where do I put the hash if I want to link to music page for example            a href="pages/music.html" (where does the hash go on the url)    does that go into the browser address bar ass mydomain.com/index2.html#music    if so thats not working for me

Comment: I don't know how you implemented it but for me it works. Here you can download my test files http://w3adventures.com/download/js/jQueryHashTest.zip
Also, have in mind that this doesn't work in all browsers when you try it locally. For me it doesn't work in Chrome but works in Firefox. It is due to Cross origin limitations.

Comment: Ive implemented it the way you have on the demo you have sent me and it just keeps reloading that main page

Comment: hmm something must be different if it works in demo and not on your page. Do you get some console errors?

Comment: I have 3 errors 2 pertaining to the script from google adsense and google analytics and the last one says....... '//@ sourceURL' and '//@ sourceMappingURL' are deprecated, please use '//# sourceURL=' and '//# sourceMappingURL=' instead.

Comment: try to implement it on your live page so I can check where is the problem